# Python сравнение двух списков

Tags: python, файлы, сортировка, списки

В общем есть файлик с конфигурацией,  config_sw1.txt, в нем строки.
Есть список ignore со словами.
Задача - считать строки из файла, вывести только те строки, которые не начинаются с '!' и в которых нет слов из списка ignore.

Код:

```
ignore = ['duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration']
currentlist = []

with open('config_sw1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] != '!' and line[0] != '\n':
            currentlist.append(line)


for line in currentlist:
    for item in ignore:
        if item in line:
            currentlist.remove(line)

for line in currentlist:
    print(line)
```

Вроде как даже работает, но почему-то часть строк не удаляется. Остаются где-то 6 строк, начинающихся на 'alias'.

Содержимое файла 'config_sw1.txt' :

```
Current configuration : 2033 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 13:11:59 UTC Thu Feb 25 2016
!
version 15.0
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname sw1
!
!
!
!
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 duplex auto
!
! 
! 
! 
! 
! 
! 
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100
 switchport mode trunk
 duplex auto
 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 duplex auto
!         
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100
 duplex auto
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk
!         
interface Ethernet1/0
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 duplex auto
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 duplex auto
!
interface Vlan100
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
!
!
alias configure sh do sh 
alias exec ospf sh run | s ^router ospf
alias exec bri show ip int bri | exc unass
alias exec id show int desc
alias exec top sh proc cpu sorted | excl 0.00%__0.00%__0.00%
alias exec c conf t
alias exec diff sh archive config differences nvram:startup-config system:running-config
alias exec shcr sh run | s ^crypto
alias exec desc sh int desc | ex down
alias exec bgp sh run | s ^router bgp
alias exec xc sh xconnect all
alias exec vc sh mpls l2tr vc
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input all
!
end
```

Вывод скрипта Python:

```
version 15.0

service timestamps debug datetime msec

service timestamps log datetime msec

no service password-encryption

hostname sw1

interface Ethernet0/0

interface Ethernet0/1

 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100

 switchport mode trunk

 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk

interface Ethernet0/2

interface Ethernet0/3

 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q

 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100

 switchport mode trunk

 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk

interface Ethernet1/0

interface Ethernet1/1

interface Ethernet1/2

interface Ethernet1/3

interface Vlan100

 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0

alias exec ospf sh run | s ^router ospf

alias exec id show int desc

alias exec c conf t

alias exec shcr sh run | s ^crypto

alias exec bgp sh run | s ^router bgp

alias exec vc sh mpls l2tr vc

line con 0

 exec-timeout 0 0

 privilege level 15

 logging synchronous

line aux 0

line vty 0 4

 login

 transport input all

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка вашего кода заключалась в том, что вы итерируетесь по списку, из которого удаляете элементы.

```
for line in currentlist:
    for item in ignore:
        if item in line:
            currentlist.remove(line)
```

Из-за этого пропускалась каждая вторая строка в последовательности строк с alias.

Чтобы уйти от этой ошибки, можно итерироваться по копии списка или генерировать новый список вместо изменения исходного:

```
# итерируемся по копии
for line in list(currentlist):
    for item in ignore:
        if item in line:
            currentlist.remove(line)

# генерируем новый
result = [line 
          for line in currentlist:
          for item in ignore:
          if item not in line]
```

---

Например, если есть код

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for value in lst:
    lst.remove(value)
```

то в результате мы получим следующий список

```
print(lst)  # [2, 4]
```

Дело в том, что итератор по списку хранит номер элемента в списке и код аналогичен следующему:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    current = lst[i]
    lst.remove(current)
    i += 1
```

И если удаление успешно, то текущий индекс увеличивать было не нужно. 
Тем не менее он увеличивается на каждой итерации цикла независимо от изменения списка, и из-за этого можно видеть эффект, когда пропускается каждое значение после удалённого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Теперь точно разобрался

Answer (score 1):

```
def line_filter(line: str, ignore=('duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration')) -> bool:
    line = line.strip()
    return line and not line.startswith('!') and not any(map(line.__contains__, ignore))

currentlist = list(filter(line_filter, open('config_sw1.txt')))

# или так

def line_filter(lines: iter, ignore=('duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration')) -> iter:
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line and not line.startswith('!') and not any(map(line.__contains__, ignore)):
            yield line

currentlist = list(line_filter(open('config_sw1.txt')))
```

Comment: Алгоритм кода: с помощью `filter` итерируется объект файла, возвращая из него строки, которые фильтруются `line_filter`, и результат приводим к списку. Самое сложное в `line_filter`: проверка что строка `line` не пуста, проверка что ее первый символ `!`, с помощью `map` каждый элемент из `ignore` вызывается в `line.__contains__` и результаты возвращаются в виде коллекции (содержащую True или False), с помощью функции `any` проверяем что хотя бы один элемент той коллекции `True` (а это значит что слово из `ignore` нашлось), но нам нужны "нормальные" строки, поэтому отрицаем результат `any`

Comment: Меня единственное что смущает в коде это в функции `line_filter` параметр `ignore`, если я захочу поменять, или добавить, то придется обернуть функцию в `filter` в лямбду: `my_ignore = ('duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration', 'service')        currentlist = list(filter(lambda x: line_filter(x, my_ignore), open('config_sw1.txt')))
` или `ignore` сделать глобальным

Comment: @gil9red Думаю в части line_filter, это работает не так. any получает генератор, map подает bool результаты по одному, до первого True. По этому, говорить что, результаты возвращаются в виде коллекции и далее уже any проверяет - некорректно. Добавление в список и проверка строки, происходит построчно, не держа все данные из файла в памяти

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример:

```
def Example(path):
    ignore = ['duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration']
    currentlist = []
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        for i in file.readlines():
            Flag = True
            if not str(i).startswith('!'):
                for j in ignore:
                    if j in i:
                        Flag = False
                if Flag:
                    currentlist.append(i.strip())
        for word in currentlist:
            print(word)
```

Использование:

```
Example(r'путь\к\файлу')
```

Comment: Не понимаю людей которые минусуют правильный ответ.

Comment: Неправильно в нем то, что вы приводите к str(i), то, что и так является str, при этом далее обращаетесь i.strip уже не приводя. Имя файла с '{}'.format, использование избыточной переменной Flag

Comment: @vadimvaduxa По поводу `str & format` вы правы, перемудрил. По поводу `Flag` я использую для того чтобы проверить каждое слово на принадлежность к строке. Ваш вариант явно качественнее, но для новичка он менее понятен.

Comment: 4 ваших строки с Flag, можно заменить на одну, более понятную if not any(j in i for j in ignore):

Answer (score -1):

Немного подправил алгоритм автора:

```
ignore = ['duplex', 'alias', 'Current configuration']
current_list = list()

with open('config_sw1.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()

        # Если пустая строка
        if not line:
            continue

        # Если начинается на '!'
        if line[0] == '!':
            continue

        # Если в строке есть строки из списка игнора
        found_ignore = False
        for item in ignore:
            if item in line:
                found_ignore = True
                break

        if found_ignore:
            continue

        current_list.append(line)


for line in current_list:
    print(line)
```

Консоль:

```
version 15.0
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
hostname sw1
interface Ethernet0/0
interface Ethernet0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk
interface Ethernet0/2
interface Ethernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 100
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast edge trunk
interface Ethernet1/0
interface Ethernet1/1
interface Ethernet1/2
interface Ethernet1/3
interface Vlan100
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input all
end
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @kolan, тогда примите ответ как правильный (галочка слева от ответа) и поставьте что ответ полезен (стрелочка вверх) ;)

Comment: @kolan, это не самый неудачный код, found_ignore, continue, break все это лишнее, посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, согласен, ваш код более короткий, но функциональный стиль его запутывает, лучше написать на несколько строк больше, но чтобы его поняли даже новички, чем с кучей вложенных друг в друга функций и лямбд, которые не сразу поймет даже сам автор (например, через несколько месяцев) :)

Comment: @gil9red я имею виду, что следовало any использовать было, а не found_ignore